# What is an effective address?

Tags: x86, x86-64, intel, memory-address, addressing-mode

While reading the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), the operation section for the LEA instruction (load effective address) uses a calculation called `EffectiveAddress(SRC)` which is not defined anywhere else.

What is the definition of *effective address* and what does `EffectiveAddress(SRC)` do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Section 3.7.5 (Specifying an Offset) of the same document states:

> The offset part of a memory address can be specified directly as a
>   static value (called a displacement) or through an address computation
>   made up of one or more of the following components:
>
> - Displacement — An 8-, 16-, or 32-bit value.
> - Base — The value in a general-purpose register.
> - Index — The value in a general-purpose register.
> - Scale factor — A value of 2, 4, or 8 that is multiplied by the index value.
>
> The offset which results from adding these components is called an
>   effective address. Each of these components can have either a positive
>   or negative (2s complement) value, with the exception of the scaling
>   factor.

*EffectiveAddress* calculates an *effective address* using:

```
Base + (Index*Scale) + Displacement
```

Comment: See also [x86 addressing modes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes/34058400#34058400).  They're all subsets of `base + index*scale + disp`, except for RIP-relative addressing in 64bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Effective address it is offset from segment base address. When you see something like `call 0x80000000` in protected mode (32-bit mode) CPU adds 0x80000000 to base address of segment pointed by CS segment register.

In 64-bit mode it equals to linear address because segmentation basically disabled.

Comment: `call 0x80000000` is a weird example, because x86 doesn't have an absolute direct form of a near [call instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call), only `call rel32`.  Do you mean a call from some address that results in EIP=0x80000000?  Some assemblers would assemble it that way, but it's an unusual example.  Also a trickier example because fetch from the new CS:EIP doesn't happen until after the `call` instruction finishes, when the next code-fetch happens, unlike with a data load/store.